# Typescript: Access Property of Interface with Property as string

Tags: javascript, typescript

How would I access a field/property of an interface with a string that represents the field in Typescript.

For instance, if we have a interface such as,

```
export interface foo {
    field1: boolean;
    field2: boolean;
```

where `foo.field1 = true`

I want to create a command that returns the value of a field such as,

```
public findValue(f: string): boolean {
    return foo.f;
}
```

However, ^ of course this does not work since `f` is a string. But is there a way to do this in Typescript?

Comment: foo[f] . as simple as that :)

Comment: Obviously, you're going to need an object that implements `foo`, because `foo` doesn't exist at runtime.

Comment: You have not defined a value named `foo`; the `interface` exists only in the type system (and as a non-primitive type, the convention would be to call it `Foo` using UpperCamelCase).  If you want `foo[f]` to work, you need a `foo`.  Please consider modifying this code to constitute a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WvpeRN).

Comment: The answer code will look [like this](https://tsplay.dev/WyvYdw), but the question should ideally be modified first.

Comment: Yes, an object is needed, and also add an indexer definition on your interface. This [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-lichterman-ndpek)  should give you an idea.